# Spring security: Form login special characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need help with problem when using spring security form login. The form login send username with escape special characters to server but spring not unescape this parameters and not found user in database.

I'm uses custom UserDetailsService but the parameter with username contains scape special characters. It's possible unescape special characters?

i'm trying unescape special characters but fail in changes.

Data:
- Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE
- Spring Security 3.1.1.RELEASE
- Tomcat 7.X

**EDIT:**

I think what the problem is solved by put enconding filter in web.xml file.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: How is your form escaping the username? Is some custom escaping done?

Comment: Works! The problem happens when the request is made by form post, but not by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anythign complex, just use the std spring set up

```
 <form name="f" id="f" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">
   <label for="j_username">E-mail :&nbsp;</label><input type='text' id='j_username' name='j_username'/><br/>
   <label for="j_password">Password :&nbsp;</label><input type='password' id='j_password' name='j_password'><br>
```

Comment: My code is very similar, i think what the problem are in server configuration. In the tomcat server.xml file connector not configured the URIEnconding to UTF-8 by legacy apps.