# Spring security and special characters

Tags: spring, security, urlencode

I need to log in with j_spring_security_check using special characters in the username and/or in the password via url

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/j_spring_security_check?j_username=username&j_password=üüü
```

isn't working and

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/j_spring_security_check?j_username=username&j_password=%c3%bc%c3%bc%c3%bc
```

(with "üüü" urlencoded)
isn't working either

Any suggestion? Let me know if you need to see any other configuration.

Thanks

Comment: This problem occurs to me as well. We have a standard login form POSTing to Spring Security, and as soon as the password contains anything like öäüéàè, logging in is not possible. The issue happens with a custom hibernate-based UserDetailsService as well as with an Ldap-based ActiveDirectory backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java Servlet standard is lamentably poor at supporting Unicode. The default of ISO-8859-1 is useless and there is still no cross-container-compatible means of configuring it to something else.

The filter method in `matteosilv`'s answer works for request bodies. For parameters in the URL, you have to use container-specific options. For example in [Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding), set `URIEncoding` on the `<Connector>` in `server.xml`; in [Glassfish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beavn.html) it's `<parameter-encoding>` in `glassfish-web.xml`.

(If you have to work in a fully cross-container-compatible manner you end up having to write your own implementation of `getParameter()`, which is sad indeed. Bad Servlet.)

However in any case it is a bad idea to pass login form fields in GET URL parameters.

This is firstly because a login causes a state-change to occur, so it is not "idempotent". This makes GET an unsuitable method and causes a load of practical problems like potentially logging you in when you navigate a page, or failing to log you in due to caching, and so on.

Secondly there are a range of ways URLs can 'leak', including referrer tracking, logging, proxies and browser history retention. Consequently you should never put any sensitive data such as a password in a URL, including in GET form submissions.

I'd suggest using a POST form submission instead, together with the `CharacterEncodingFilter`.

Comment: Yeah I don't like it either, but it's customer's code and I have no say in it. It is used to authenticate from a C# application over the intranet so logging/proxies/history shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was actually solved for me by moving the CharacterEncodingFilter ABOVE the SpringSecurityFilterChain in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an encodingFilter in the web.xml file could be helpful:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

source: [Spring security: Form login special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880366/spring-security-form-login-special-characters)

Comment: Nope, I already tried that. Note that login from the web form is working as expected (referring to your source). It is just the URL that isn't working for me.