# Spring Security with Custom Authentication Provider doesn't work with special characters in user name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding, spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.2.6.RELEASE and I have implemented my own custom authentication provider in order to handle different kinds of failed logins. I have a requirement to enable special characters in the user name. However I can't bring this to work.

Here's my login form:

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <!-- Table -->
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><msg:message code="label.username"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><msg:message code="label.password"/></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I've also included the org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter in my web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

It is right before the the spring security filter:

```
<!-- spring security -->
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

So what am I missing here? The login page is utf-8 encoded and when I check with FF Developers Tools/Firebug the username paramater is sent correctly - userä. On debugging in my CustomAuthenticationProvider:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = null;
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

    // credentials given by the user
    String username = (String)auth.getPrincipal();
    String password = (String)auth.getCredentials();
```

I see that username is "userÃ¤" and the login fails.

Thank you all for the help!
al

Comment: If it helps, "ä" decoding to "Ã¤" indicates that the ISO 8859-1 encoding is being used somewhere, as that's what the UTF-8 representation of "ä" - `C3 A4` - decodes to in this charset.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302065/spring-security-and-special-characters). If you're running your Spring application in a servlet container, that might be the culprit.

Comment: @MelvinKicchi thanks for the comment. I've looked everywhere in my code for ISO 8859-1 and found nothing. Perhaps it is somewhere deep in spring security. I'll keep looking for some hidden encoding settings. Tomcat configuration in connector is already set to UTF-8.

Comment: OK, found my mistake : <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name> is of course wrong. changed it to <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> and now it works just fine.

Comment: Woot! Glad everything's working for you now. \o/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
```

should be

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Now it works.